# How to link and built a project when your external SDK only has .dll, .lib, .h files

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, sdk, dllimport

I have an external SDK that only contains a .dll, .lib, and .h files. I'm trying to use the SDK. Nothing in the dll is readable, but the .h files have some comments about the methods.
I'm not very c++ savvy. I assume I need to load the library, then read from the dll using the methods that are defined in the .h files. Correct?

I need to know how to write a cpp project where I can link all these files, read the dll, and be able to use the methods that are defined in the sdk.
Is there a test project with the project setup where I can see how this can be done?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You probably just need to link with the library and the header files, and have the dll in the application directory. What SDK are you using? That would probably help.

Comment: Simple. Include the header file in your source code, just as you'd include any other header file. Link the lib file when linking. Put the dll in the same directory as your executable. That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's several ways to achieve this, including a shortcut method using `#pragma` that I'm *not* going to recommend in case it leads you to develop poor habits.

Similarly, you can use *Property Sheets*, but that may seem a bit overwhelming to start with.  So I'm going to give you the standard middle-of-the-road approach...

In your project settings (Alt-F7 or *Project > Properties...*), you need to set these options:

- **C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories**

  Add the folder you want to be searched when using the `#include` directive.  Without complicating this with personal preference and style considerations, just set this to the directory where the SDK's header file lives.

  You can use absolute or relative paths, environment variables.  Whatever.  I suggest for now you just use absolute path.
- **Linker > General > Additional Library Directories**

  Same as above, but this is where the **.lib** file resides.
- **Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies**

  This is the name of your lib file.

Now, if you `#include` the SDK's header file in your project's source and compile, it should hopefully work.  And the linking step should also succeed.

If not, there may be extra things you need to make the SDK play nice (such as preprocessor definitions, compiler settings, or additional dependencies).

The last thing you need to worry about is that running your program might fail because the DLL cannot be found, unless it lives in a specific place that Windows searches.  Rather than mess with DLL search paths etc, you can use a *Post-Build Event* to copy the DLL to the same directory where your executable was built.

Still, in the project properties:

- **Build Events > Post-Build Event**

  Add a command line something like:

  ```
  copy "\Path\To\MySDK\MySDK.dll" "$(OutDir)\"
  ```

Now you should be all set to go, and not have to think about it again!

Comment: Thanks! You saved me!
Almost just to add to this answer, I realized with this approach I don't need to use LoadLibrary() anymore!